# Warning:preg_match error (class.upload.php)

Tags: php, preg-match

Verot upload class (class.upload.php v3.2) gives an eror while upload and mime check.

```
if (preg_match("/^([\.-\w]+)\/([\.-\w]+)(.*)$/i", $this->file_src_mime)) {
                            $this->file_src_mime = preg_replace("/^([\.-\w]+)\/([\.-\w]+)(.*)$/i", '$1/$2', $this->file_src_mime);
                            $this->log .= '-&nbsp;MIME validated as ' . $this->file_src_mime . '<br />';
                        } else {
                            $this->file_src_mime = null;
}
```

This occurs an error:

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 7 in class.upload.php on line 2616

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: `-` should be escaped too - `\-` Or put in the end of block `[\.\w-]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[\.-\w]` is illegal because `\w` is a character class, not a character. As written, your regex is looking for characters in the range `.` to `\w`, which makes no sense.

It's not clear to me what you are trying to do, but you can't do this.

I think you *may* want `.`, `-`, or word characters (anything matched by `\w`), in which case you should use `[.\-\w]`.

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed in the latest version, which you can now find on Github:
https://github.com/verot/class.upload.php
(Creator of the class here)